# Emploi de « triptyque » signifiant projet/plan comportant trois volets : est-il courant ? registre ?

Tags: usage, registre, grec, académique

Source [TLFi : triptyque](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/triptyque)

> Plan, projet qui comporte trois parties. Déterminer préalablement l'activité probable de l'entreprise, confronter périodiquement cette hypothèse raisonnable aux réalités, prendre ensuite les décisions appropriées, tel est le triptyque du contrôle budgétaire.

L'emploi du mot triptyque comme ci-dessous est-il courant ? Le mot peut-il employé dans un registre soutenu seulement ? P.ex. la phrase ci-dessous sera-t-elle compréhensible ?

> Ayant étant deux ans et demi chercheur post-doctoral au sein de
> l'équipe X, je connais le savoir-faire du laboratoire qui s'appuie
> sur le triptyque expérience-modélisation-simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est un terme du domaine de la peinture qui par extension est applicable dans les domaines de la littérature et de la musique pour désigner des œuvres en trois parties et aussi dans le domaine des entreprises en général ; dans ce dernier domaine il réfère au projets et au plans que ces entreprises génèrent ou qui leur sont associés ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/triptyque)).

Le mot est courant [globalement](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=triptyque+&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctriptyque%3B%2Cc0) et surtout dans le domaine des arts et de la littérature.

Le premier emploi est gauche ; le mot est utilisé comme si le contrôle budgétaire était connu pour comporter trois parties ;

> Déterminer préalablement l'activité probable de l'entreprise, confronter périodiquement cette hypothèse raisonnable aux réalités, prendre ensuite les décisions appropriées, constituent un triptyque fondamental définissant du contrôle budgétaire.

En ce qui concerne le second emploi, il est recherché aussi, et donc comme tout ce qui est recherché n'est pas courant, il n'est pas courant ; seulement on ne peut pas dire que l'expression soit caractérisée par la banalité des termes.  Certaines modifications peuvent être nécessaires ; s'il n'existe qu'une méthodologie dans le travail de laboratoire considéré il faut une virgule. Autrement, c'est sans problème.

> Ayant été deux ans et demi chercheur post-doctoral au sein de l'équipe X, je connais le savoir-faire du laboratoire, qui s'appuie sur le triptyque expérience-modélisation-simulation.